# SQL request in TecDoc2016 database returns incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get correct category from TecDoc2016 database by article of the part.

Right now my query for part with article '96494264' (it's an oil pressure sensor)

```
"select distinct 
  article_oe.OENbr, 
  passanger_car_trees.* 
from
  `tecdoc`.`article_oe` 
left join 
 `tecdoc`.`suppliers` on `suppliers`.`id` = `article_oe`.`supplierid` 
left join
  `tecdoc`.`article_links` on `article_links`.`supplierid` = `article_oe`.`supplierid` 
  and
   `article_links`.`datasupplierarticlenumber` = `article_oe`.`datasupplierarticlenumber` 
left join
  `tecdoc`.`passanger_car_prd` on `passanger_car_prd`.`id` = `article_links`.`linkageId` 
left join 
 `tecdoc`.`passanger_car_pds` on `passanger_car_pds`.`productid` = `article_links`.`linkageId` 
left join 
  `tecdoc`.`passanger_car_trees` on `passanger_car_trees`.`id` = `passanger_car_pds`.`nodeid` 
where `article_oe`.`OENbr` = 96494264"
```

returns a bunch of results, from valves to screws.

How can I narrow the result of the request?

Comment: Without sample data and results, we really don't know what YOU mean by "incorrect results".  A db<>fiddle of some sort would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the TecDoc database schema is too large even without data. I found no db fiddle which could work with it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think due to `left join` it is returning more rows. Try changing it to `join` if non-matching rows are not required. It would be better to add the condition in `join` instead of `where`.

```
select distinct 
  article_oe.OENbr, 
  passanger_car_trees.* 
from
  tecdoc.article_oe 
join 
 tecdoc.suppliers on suppliers.id = article_oe.supplierid and article_oe.OENbr = 96494264
join
  tecdoc.article_links on article_links.supplierid = article_oe.supplierid 
  and
   article_links.datasupplierarticlenumber = article_oe.datasupplierarticlenumber 
join
  tecdoc.passanger_car_prd on passanger_car_prd.id = article_links.linkageId 
join 
 tecdoc.passanger_car_pds on passanger_car_pds.productid = article_links.linkageId 
join 
  tecdoc.passanger_car_trees on passanger_car_trees.id = passanger_car_pds.nodeid
```